# Show that every non-constant positive solution is periodic.

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, nonlinear-system

#### Full problem:

Consider the predator-prey model with $\dot{x} = x(1-y)$ and $\dot{y} = (2x-1)y$. Show that every non-constant positive solution is periodic.

#### My Answer:

First off we can see here that we have two equilibrium points, $E_1 = (0,0)$, and $E_2 = \left( \frac{1}{2},1 \right)$. Since we only care about the non constant positive solutions, we will focus our efforts on $E_2$.

$$Df\left(x , y \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} 1-y & -x \\ 2y & 2x-1 \end{matrix}\right)$$
So,
$$Df\left( \frac{1}{2}, 1 \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \\ 2 & 0\end{matrix}\right) \implies \lambda_{1,2} = \pm i$$

Thus, since we get complex eigenvalues with a zero real part, this implies that we have a center at the point $\left(\frac{1}{2},1 \right)$. Thus, since there are no more positive equilibrium points, all positive nonconstant solutions of the system must be periodic.

I think this is correct, but I'm not sure if there's more I need to say since we are wanting to show this for ALL non-constant positive solutions. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the fact that there are no more positive equilibrium points does not show the solutions are periodic.

Hint: find a function $F(x,y)$ that is constant on any solution.

Further hint: the differential equation $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{(2x-1)y}{x(1-y)}$ is separable.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean then that I need a Lyapunov function and show that it's derivative is equal to zero? I've been trying to avoid Lyapunov functions if possible if you can't tell (seeing as how this is the 3rd problem of mine you've answered). How would I go about finding that function then? Is it just guess and check?

Comment: So using your second hint, I found that by splitting the variables and integrating, I got that $\ln (y) -y = 2x - \ln (x) + C$. Does this lead me in the right direction? If so, what does this tell me? Thanks!

Comment: Good.  So is $\ln(y) - y - 2 x + \ln(x)$ constant on a solution?  And what do the curves $\ln(y) - y - 2 x + \ln(x) = C$ look like?

Comment: Ah! Yes! It is a constant solution because $\ln(y) - y -2x + \ln(x) = C$. So since all of those solutions are closed curves, then we know that all of the non-constant positive solutions are periodic. Is this correct?